# how to make css @media property inline ( about email responsive)

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to make my registration email responisve in mobile device,
and I wanna give @media property a try, but I cannot figure out how to make this inline,  as I know, email's style should always be embedded...
the doc do not refer to that

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put it inline, you will have to put it in the head tags of html email within style tags. For example:

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    ...
    ...
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Media Queries is the best option
but

Support for media queries is vastly different across email clients. Many clients, such as Gmail, don't support media queries at all.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


.container {
  max-width:600px!important;
  display:block!important;
  margin:0 auto!important;
  clear:both!important;
}
```